# History.push does not redirect when only the param changes but it changes the url in the browser

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom, react-router-v4, react-router-redux

I have this route:

```
   <PrivateRoute path="/profile/:user_id" exact component={GenericProfile} />;
```

This is the `PrivateRoute` component:

```
const PrivateRoute = ({ component: Component, auth, ...rest }) => {
  return (
    <Route
      {...rest}
      render={(props) =>
        auth.isAuthenticated === true ? (
          <Component {...props} />
        ) : (
          <Redirect to="/login" />
        )
      }
    />
  );
};

PrivateRoute.propTypes = {
  auth: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
};

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  auth: state.auth,
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(PrivateRoute);
```

This is how it's used in **App.js**:

When i am in a profile page and I have a button that redirects to another profile:

```
    <Button onClick={()=>{
       this.props.history.push("/profile/" + another_user_id)
                   }}>
      Redirect to another profile
    </Button>
```

The url in the browser changes, but nothing happens.
I don't actually get redirect to the other profile.

**NOTE:**
This seems to be a recurring problem for many developers. None of the proposed solutions worked for me. So I am writing this because I have a doubt my case is a bit different.

Comment: You didn't explain what `this.props.history` points to. Sounds like it's supposed to be a wrapper around [history.pushState](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History/pushState) where you update the UI and update the URL instead of reloading a page. If you just want to redirect to a new page, use `location.href = "new/url.html"`

Comment: You need a useEffect with the urlParam, so it reloads the new data. If you show us the full profile page I could give you a working example

Comment: If you're using `withRouter` (you didn't specify), see the Important Note in https://reactrouter.com/web/api/withRouter